# Why this feed doesn't validate

Tags: validation, rss, feed

http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2FVideoRicette

it tells me that there's an invalid character but I can't find it

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the value for href:

```
<a href="Ve l'ho promessa settimana scorsa... ecco finalmente la zuppa di cipolla http://www.mauriziopz.eu/ricette/index.php/2010/03/zuppa-di-cipolle/  e qui puoi trovare il mio dvd http://www.mauriziopz.eu/ricette/index.php/2009/12/comprerai-questo-dvd-di-video-ricette/">http://www.mauriziopz.eu/ricette/index.php/2009/12/comprerai-questo-dvd-di-video-ricette/</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source code of the feed. The link contains all of this:

```
<a href="Ve l'ho promessa settimana scorsa... ecco finalmente la zuppa di cipolla http://www.mauriziopz.eu/ricette/index.php/2010/03/zuppa-di-cipolle/  e qui puoi trovare il mio dvd http://www.mauriziopz.eu/ricette/index.php/2009/12/comprerai-questo-dvd-di-video-ricette/">http://www.mauriziopz.eu/ricette/index.php/2009/12/comprerai-questo-dvd-di-video-ricette/</a>
```

And that definitely is not a valid URI.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is this line:
    `<a href="Ve l'ho promessa settimana scorsa... ecco finalmente la zuppa di cipolla http://www.mauriziopz.eu/ricette/index.php/2010/03/zuppa-di-cipolle/  e qui puoi trovare il mio dvd http://www.mauriziopz.eu/ricette/index.php/2009/12/comprerai-questo-dvd-di-video-ricette/">http://www.mauriziopz.eu/ricette/index.php/2009/12/comprerai-questo-dvd-di-video-ricette/</a></p>`

The apostrofe ( ' ) should probably be encoded. I see you use `&#8217;` in other cases.